# SqlCeConnection is way slower than SqlConnection

Tags: c#, performance, sql-server-ce, sqlconnection

In my C# app I can switch between Online SQL-Server connection and local SQLCE (sdf file) connection. Both DBs are the same in structure and indexes.

But using the local SDF file through SqlCeConnection is so much slower - 20 times slower when doing a lot of calls.

Example:

```
using (DbConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (DbCommand cmd = GetSqlCommand("select * from t", connection))
    {
        try
        {
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ...
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {  }
    }
}
```

What is going on here - can I optimize that?

Comment: Keep a single connection open and unused for the lifetime of your app

Comment: @Erik, would that not depend on how juergen is using it? ADO.NET implements connection pooling, so repeatedly opening and closing connections has good performance. We really need to see an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DourHighArch while ADO.NET has some pooling primitives, the actual details are left to the specific provider; it is entirely possible that the CE client does not use pooling

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @DourHighArch You are wrong! I perfectly understand the question, and SQLCE does not have connection pooling.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a single connection open and unused for the lifetime of your app, SQL Compact does not have connection pooling.

In addition, opening a SqlCeConnection can be slow because of:

- The database file has been created on another platform
- The ACL (Access Control List) on the RSA folder is corrupt
- Invalid Internet Proxy configuration

More info here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/08/faq-why-is-opening-my-sql-server.html

Comment: And if the OP is only one using the connection there is no down side.

Comment: @paparazzo Sqlce is an embedded database

Comment: Exactly.  There is no down side I can think of.